# How do you add a file as a param in scalaj-http for a multipart/form-data request?

Tags: scala, http, twitter

I'm trying to use scalaj-http to send an POST request for twitter upload. Ive attached the documentation of what they require for the request. The part I'm having trouble with is trying to pass in the actual binary file as a parameter for "media". I can only seem to see how to do postMulti which is just the file and then add parameter but not actually pass in the data as a parameter.

```
val appendResponse = Http(twitterApiUrl)
  .postMulti(MultiPart("media", "Output.bin", "application/mac-binary", byteArray))
  .postForm(Seq("command" -> "APPEND", "media_id" -> twitterMediaID, "segment_index" -> "0"))
  .oauth(consumer = consumer, token = access)
  .asString
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http/issues/170

The fix for the issue is documented on this github issue link

Comment: Good to see there is a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use "media" instead of "Output" as the name of your MultiPart, and not use "media" in your params.

**Update:** I used Charles to trace the requests and didn't find anything that looked wrong to me (after changing 'Output' to 'media'). The below code is not really a fix for your code, but more of a workaround:

```
val appendResponse = Http("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
    .postForm
    .params(
        Seq(
            "command" -> "APPEND",
            "media_id" -> twitterMediaID,
            "segment_index" -> "0",
            "media_data" -> Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(byteArray)
        )
    )
    .oauth(consumer, token)
    .asString
```

This resulted in a 204 response for me, I didn't further test if I could get a full file to upload.

Also note that this uses the media_data (base64) version, and also 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of 'multipart/form-data' as specified by the documentation. So according to the docs it is incorrect.

Comment: I've made those changes but I'm still unable to get a 200 on the request

Comment: So what _is_ the response that you are getting? Any hints in there?

Comment: HttpResponse({"errors":[{"code":38,"message":"media parameter is missing."}]},

Comment: when I was using params i was getting a 401 authorization error, now that Ive changed it to postform I'm getting that media parameter missing error

Comment: I don't think you should combine postMulti and postForm, your usage of params combined with postMulti was OK I think. If that gives a 401 you need to (first) look into your authorization flow.

Comment: I use the same .oauth in a request before that returns a success 200, so I'm pretty sure its not my tokens that are the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth: I do get the same error as you get using a multipart post, and looking at the request using Charles doesn't give me any hints on how to resolve the issue. However, using application/x-www-form-urlencoded (not allowed by the documentation) and media_data instead of data seems to work.

Comment: How were you able to pass in the bytearray through the media_data parameter without using mutlipart? Do you mind posting your code?

Comment: If you use base64 encoding the bytearray becomes a string, and is therefore usable as a 'normal' parameter. The code I used is in my answer.